# Proof of Eberlein–Smulian Theorem for a reflexive Banach spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, banach-spaces

Looking for the proof of Eberlein-Smulian Theorem.

Searching for the proof is what I break with this morning. Some of my friends recommend Haim Brezis (*Functional Analysis, Sobolev Spaces and Partial
Differential Equations*). After I search the book, I only found the statement of the theorem, is the proof very difficult to grasp? Why is Haim Brezis skip it in his book?

Please I need a reference where I can find the proof in detail.

---

> **Theorem**:(Eberlein-Smul'yan Theorem) A Banach space $E$ is reflexive if and
>   only if every (norm) bounded sequence in $E$ has a subsequence which converges
>   weakly to an element of $E$.

---

Comment: -1: I quote from Brézis right after stating the theorem as Theorem 3.19: *The proof of Theorem 3.19 is rather delicate and is omitted; see e.g. R. Holmes [1], K. Yosida [1], N. Dunford-J.T. Schwartz [1], Diestel [2], or Problem 10.* What more do you want?

Comment: @t.b.: Nothing.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

- I think Megginson's book **An Introduction to Banach Space Theory** (GTM 183) is worth having look at. You can preview some parts of the book at [Google Books](http://books.google.com/books?hl=sk&id=fD-GeCsqoqkC&pg=PA248). (I believe the whole section 2.8 *Weak Compactness* might be interesting for you.)
- Albiac–Kalton, *[Topics in Banach Space Theory](http://books.google.com/books/about/Topics_in_Banach_Space_Theory.html?id=FkjCulO5xg0C)* (GTM 233), Corollary 1.6.4, page 24.
- Whitley, *[An elementary proof of the Eberlein–Šmulian theorem](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF01350091)*, Mathematische Annalen **172** (2), 1967, 116–118. Freely available from [GDZ](http://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/dms/load/img/?PPN=PPN235181684_0172&DMDID=DMDLOG_0027).
- Zeidler, [Nonlinear functional analysis and its applications. II/A: Linear monotone operators](http://books.google.com/books?id=sk1M2Vw-Y24C&pg=PA255), Springer, 1990, Theorem 21.D
- Theo Buhler, Dietmar A. Salamon, [Functional Analysis](https://people.math.ethz.ch/%7Esalamon/PREPRINTS/funcana.pdf) (GSM 191), [Theorem 3.4.1, page 134](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Functional_Analysis/6lxoDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&pg=134)

I made this answer CW, so that other people can add further references if they think it's suitable.

Answer (score 1):

Kôsaku Yosida, Functional Analysis, Springer 1980, Chapter V, Appendix, section 4. (This appears to be the 6th edition).