# Subnet or subsequence in Weak Topology?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, weak-convergence, topological-vector-spaces

Let $A$  be a convex and weakly compact subset of a Banach space $X$, and  $\{x_n\}$ is a sequence in $A$, can we say   $\{x_n\}$  has a weakly convergence sub sequence in $A$ ?

Comment: Isn't that just the definition of weak compactness?

Comment: No, notice the word "sub sequence". Weak topology is not magnetizable in general.

Answer (score 0):

I found the Answer of my own question :)

Thanks to [Eberlein_ Smulian theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/706748/what-does-weakly-compact-mean-when-applied-to-subsets-x-subset-y/766591#766591) the answer is positive!